# How to make Javascript alert code all on one line

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alerts

I'm trying to figure out how to make the alert code "First and Last Name must be filled out" if both of the fields of the form have no information inserted. I know how to do them individually, but how do you do make an alert code for both messages combined on one line? I am pretty new to Javascript..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First Name is missing information");
        return false;
    }
    else (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Last Name is missing information")
        return false;
    }
    else (x == null || x == "" && y == null || y == "") {
        alert("First and Last name are missing information")
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So...is your question answered?

Answer (score 4):

Delete all your JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="post">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" required /><br />
  Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lname" required /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice the `required` attribute on the form.

Don't use JavaScript to do HTML's job.

Comment: This is ideal in modern browsers, but doesn't account for validation messaging or if requirements dictate support down to older IE versions.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic needs to be reversed so that the case where both are null is checked first or the code will never get to it because either the `x` or `y` case happens first. Try:

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
var emptyX = x == null || x == "";
var emptyY = y == null || y == "";
if (emptyX && emptyY) {
    alert("First and Last name are missing information")
    return false;
}
else (emptyX) {
    alert("First Name is missing information");
    return false;
}
else (emptyY) {
    alert("Last Name is missing information")
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should move your final `else` statement to the top. As your code currently exists, both fields will not be checked if either the first or last names are found to be empty.

Alternatively, you could add logic in each of `x` and `y` to check if the other is not empty but this isn't necessary if you just reverse the code.